# AR Core FLutter Plugin Error on Manifest File

Tags: flutter, augmented-reality, arcore

```
Parameter format not correct -
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (241, 38): Object is not abstract and does not implement abstract member public abstract fun onActivityCreated(@NonNull p0: Activity, @Nullable p1: Bundle?): Unit defined in android.app.Application.ActivityLifecycleCallbacks
e: D:\flutter\.pub-cache\hosted\pub.dartlang.org\arcore_flutter_plugin-0.0.10\android\src\main\kotlin\com\difrancescogianmarco\arcore_flutter_plugin\ArCoreView.kt: (242, 13): 'onActivityCreated' overrides nothing

FAILURE: Build failed with an exception.

* What went wrong:
```

I get Above Error on Build/Debug.

Followed the Plugin Installation Instruction on Below Link:

https://pub.dev/packages/arcore_flutter_plugin

Answer (score 1):

After Struggle I managed to Fix it, The Issue is the Plugin Itself.

Had to remove "?" from onActivityCreated

As Below:

Before

> override fun onActivityCreated(
> activity: Activity?,
> savedInstanceState: Bundle?
> )

After:

> override fun onActivityCreated(
> activity: Activity,
> savedInstanceState: Bundle?
> )

Comment: Update:
This Particular issue is related to Null Safety. Make Sure to Upgrade your Code to Null Safety SDK and enable NUll Safety if you want to use Null Safety version of Plugin